# Varaha Jayanti : Is there any scriptural reference?

Tags: vishnu, scripture, varaha

It seems like on 4th Sept., as per the [Hindu Calendar](http://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/varaha/varaha-jayanti-date-time.html?year=2016), there is Varaha Jayanti. Usually Jayanti refer to the birth. As per this [link](http://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/varaha/varaha-jayanti-date-time.html?year=2016) it is stated that this day is celebrated as the birth anniversary of Lord Vishnu.

Of course, Varaha (Sanskrit: वराह, "boar") is the avatar of the Hindu god Vishnu in the form of a boar and as per Hinduism, [Varaha](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=DH0vmD8ghdMC&pg=PA444&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) symbolizes the resurrection of the earth from a `pralaya` dissolution of the universe and the establishment of a new `kalpa`

**My Question**: Is there a scriptural ref. which explicitly states Varaha birth/Jayanti with month/year information?

Comment: I think it's probably a misprint / typo , because Shriman Narayana has no birth anniversary. It indicates birth anniversary of Varaha Avatar, who incarnated at the beginning of this kalpa that is why this kalpa is aka ShwetaVaraha Kalpa. ShwetaVaraha -> White Boar.

Comment: @Yogi what is misprint? it seems that the way Krishna Jayanti is celebrated some region/people also celebrate Varaha Jayanti. The way Krishna birth is explicitly mentioned in scriptures I am looking for similar ref. for Varaha avatar.

Comment: Well I guess it would be a misprint and yeah certainly people celebrate shri varaha avatar jayanti. There is a varaha temple in thirupati it is said that lord appeared in varaha avatar in thirumala hills so maybe that temple celebrates it as janmastami.